# Error in using wso2 stratos as openid consumer

Tags: wso2

I am attempting to do a login into wso2 stratos 1.5.1 Identity Server using openid at my local instance at

cloud-test.wso2.com:9443/carbon/relyingparty/index.jsp

regardless of the openid url that i input i get the following error:

```
Error! Relying Party initialization failed
```

**Update:**

With a stand alone instance of wso2 Identity server 3.2.3 I am able to go through the process of logging in via openid ../carbon/relyingparty/index.jsp

As another side note the two way authentication does not work with the stratos version of Identity Server also.

What is up with stratos? What is the difference that is causing these two services to fail?

What could be the problem here?

**Second Update:**

I found a jira issue that might be related , but not sure, at

[https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-11757?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-11757?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab)

This tells me that perhaps stratos is broken and will not be fixed?

**In the process of trying to get a consumer working with a provider (both wso2 stand alone Identity Servers) I have attempted the following:**

I have a second stand alone Identity Server now running instead of stratos IS. I can use /carbon/relyingparty/index.jsp to reach places such as yahoo openid and myopenid urls. However, when I attempt connection to the provider instance of Identity Server I get the following error :

```
Invalid openid2.provider URL
```

Does anybody have an idea of why this error happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to experiment more and ask another question at

[wso2 identity server Multifactor Authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143776/wso2-identity-server-multifactor-authentication-error)

to come to a solution.

The issue is that the default credentials to authenticate to gtalk are incorrect. Update with your own to make this work.