# wso2 identity server Multifactor Authentication error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am unable to implement Multifactor Authentication .

The error i am getting is

```
TID: [0] [WSO2 Identity Server] [2012-10-30 10:31:38,620] ERROR     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.xmpp.MPAuthenticationProvider} -  login failed. Trying     again.. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.xmpp.MPAuthenticationProvider}
SASL authentication failed: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate    (SASLAuthentication.java:209)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:341)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:301)
```

This is for wso2 Identity Server 3.2.3 . Straight out of the box. No additional configuration performed to run this instance of Identity Server.

It appears that signing in as admin , the ldap authentication is completed and then authentication with gtalk is attempted when the error occurs.

Should I be setting my own configuration in the identity.xml where gtalk is being set?

```
<MultifactorAuthentication>

    <XMPPSettings>

        <XMPPConfig>

            <XMPPProvider>gtalk</XMPPProvider>

            <XMPPServer>talk.google.com</XMPPServer>

            <XMPPPort>5222</XMPPPort>

            <XMPPExt>gmail.com</XMPPExt>

            <XMPPUserName>multifactor1@gmail.com</XMPPUserName>

            <XMPPPassword>wso2carbon</XMPPPassword>

        </XMPPConfig>

    </XMPPSettings>

</MultifactorAuthentication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I do need to set up a Google talk account.

1. I added the new settings to the MultifactorAuthentication configuration.
2. I restarted the server.
3. I edited the user account with another new Google talk account.
4. I logged out.
5. Logged back in via relyingparty URL with openid,
6. received communication over gtalk requesting pin.
7. I entered the pin and got logged in.

It would have been nice if wso2 had I their documentation the need to setup the settings for this configuration to get multifactor authentication to work out of the box.